# Does the triple equal sign (===) behave differently in AssemblyScript?

Tags: equality, assemblyscript

A vendor I use packages their software with AssemblyScript. They provide some infrastructure and I build on top of it.

Accidentally, I changed my double equal signs ("==") to triple equal signs ("===") in a function that performs equality checks on hexadecimal strings. I spent hours ensuring that the values checked are indeed equal and have the same case sensitivity, but nothing could make the if statement enter the branch I was expecting it to enter, except for going back to "==".

And so I ended up here, asking for help. How is "===" different to "==" in AssemblyScript? Is it some quirk of the language itself or the vendor's parser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. In AssemblyScript tripple equal ("===") compare raw references and skip overloading operator ("=="). See [docs](https://docs.assemblyscript.org/basics#the-case-of).

There are have proposal avoid this non-standard for TypeScript behaviour. You could check and upvote [this issue](https://github.com/AssemblyScript/assemblyscript/issues/856)